# Crystal Reports through stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

i try to create crystal reports in vs08 using sqlserver2008r2 and here first  when i start to create reports  i add new item  and click on dataset then create tables then after this i  add item crystal reports and then call this tables in ado.net

like this in dataset and its very long

[image: pic]

this seems where long procedure .. i want to create reports through store procedures can here anyone tell me what i can do for this?

Answer (score 0):

1.create a SP that rerurns data.
2.create a Crystal report with a Datasource, select your SP from the datasource.
3.now your database fields will appear in field explorer.
4.use those fields to display